# An unappealing arrow using `to[out=*,in=**]` in `TikZ`

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

The diagram that I have is almost what I want. The unappealing part of it is the arrow from $180^{\circ}-\theta$.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

%AT is a chord of a circle, and B is a point on the circle distinct from A and T. \ell is a
%tangent line to the circle at T. \angle{ABT} and one of the angles between AT and \ell are
%supplementary angles.

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (0,0) circle (1.5);

\path (230:1.5) coordinate (A) (110:1.5) coordinate (B) (325:1.5) coordinate (B') (20:1.5) coordinate (T);
\draw[fill] (T) circle (1.5pt);
\path let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+\n2)}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A) +({0.5*(\n1+\n2)+180}:0.15)$){\textit{A}};
\path let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*((\n1-180)+\n2)}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(B) +({0.5*((\n1-180)+\n2)+180}:0.15)$){\textit{B}};
\node[anchor=200, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(T) +(20:0.15)$){\textit{T}};


%Line \ell is drawn. T is to be the midpoint of the drawn line.
\path[name path=line_ell] ($(T) +(110:1.25)$) -- ($(T) +(-70:1)$);
\path[name path=right_arrowhead_of_line_ell] (1.5,0) -- (1.75,0);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=line_ell and right_arrowhead_of_line_ell, by=a_point_near_right_arrowhead_of_line_ell}];
\coordinate (right_arrowhead_of_line_ell) at ($(a_point_near_right_arrowhead_of_line_ell) +(-70:1.4)$);
\path let \p1=($(T)-($(right_arrowhead_of_line_ell)$)$) in coordinate (left_arrowhead_of_line_ell) at ($(T) +(110:{veclen(\x1,\y1)})$);
\draw[latex-latex] (left_arrowhead_of_line_ell) -- (right_arrowhead_of_line_ell);
\node[anchor=110, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(right_arrowhead_of_line_ell) +(-70:0.1)$){$\ell$};


%Point S is located.
\coordinate (S) at ($(T) +(110:1.55)$);
\draw[fill] (S) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=200, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(S) +(20:0.15)$){\textit{S}};


%Chords of the circle are drawn.
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw[dashed] (B') -- (A);
\draw[dashed] (B') -- (T);
\draw (A) -- (T);
\draw (A) -- (T);
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (B) -- ($(T) +({\n1+180}:0.55)$);



%The marks indicating the measures \angle{ATS} and \angle{AB'T} are drawn. They are labeled \theta.
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(A)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(T) +(110:0.25)$) arc (110:{\n1+180}:0.25);
\draw let\p1=($(A)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={0.5*((\n1+180)+110)-180}, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(T) +({0.5*((\n1+180)+110)}:0.3)$){$\theta$};
%
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(B')-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(B')$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(B') +(\n1:0.25)$) arc (\n1:{\n2+180}:0.25);
\draw let \p1=($(B')-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(B')$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))-180}, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(B') +({0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))}:0.3)$){$\theta$};


%The marks indicating the measures \angle{ATS} and \angle{AB'T} are drawn. They are labeled \theta.
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(B) +(\n2:0.35)$) arc (\n2:{\n1-180}:0.35);
\draw[latex-,shorten <=1pt] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)}, \n3={0.5*((\n1-180)+\n2)} in ($(B) +(\n3:0.45)$) to[out=\n3, in=0, looseness=2] ++(-20pt,7.5pt) node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\tiny]{$180^\circ-\theta$};



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about just doing `\draw[latex-,shorten <=1pt] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)}, \n3={0.5*((\n1-180)+\n2)} in ($(B) +(\n3:0.45)$) 
to[out=\n3, in=-60, looseness=2] ++(-20pt,7.5pt) 
node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\tiny]{$180^\circ-\theta$};` or 
`\draw[latex-,shorten <=1pt] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)}, \n3={0.5*((\n1-180)+\n2)} in ($(B) +(\n3:0.45)$) 
to[out=\n3, in=0, looseness=2] ++(-20pt,-15pt) 
node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\tiny]{$180^\circ-\theta$};`?

Comment: why you not use  one of answers on your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444628/an-error-using-toout-in-in-tikz as base, and than define arrows on your choice (by using library `arrows.meta` ? your code is unnecessary complicated ...

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, an option using contour to put some labels forward of the lines,then postaction trick to draw white line and black arrow forward to contour the arrows, and an option example using controls, that could be easily edited in TikzEdt. The framework used is tkz-euclide, that for this case has two macros to draw tangents.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetkzobj{all}
\contourlength{2pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Set limits.
        \tkzInit[xmin=-4,xmax=14.5,ymax=6.5, ymin=-5]
        %\tkzGrid[sub,color=red!20!,subxstep=.2,subystep=.2]
        \tkzClip
        %Define principal points.
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[O](230:3){A}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[O](110:3){B}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[O](325:3){C}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[O](2.5,3.2){S} % From random point external to the circle.
        \tkzTangent[from=S](O,A) \tkzGetPoints{U}{T}

        %Define secondary points.
        \tkzDefPoint(9,0){O'}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[O'](230:3){A'}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[O'](110:3){B'}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[O'](325:3){C'}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[O'](10:3){T'}
        \tkzTangent[at=T'](O')\tkzGetPoint{h'} % h is a point in the tangent line and 1cm distance from T'
        \tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=3.5](T',h')\tkzGetPoint{S'} % Allows to find a point k distances in the line T'-h'

        %Draw the circles
        \tkzDrawCircle[R,blue](O,3cm)
        \tkzDrawCircle[R,blue](O',3cm)

        % Draw all the angles
        \tkzMarkAngle[fill=blue!15,size=1.5,thick](A,B,T)       
        \tkzMarkAngle[fill=blue, fill opacity=0.2, size=0.7](T,C,A)
        \tkzDrawSegments[thick](B,T) % Must be traced before STA angle
        \tkzMarkAngle[fill=blue!20,fill opacity=0.8, size=0.7](S,T,A)

        \tkzMarkAngle[fill=blue!15,mkpos=1, size=0.7](A',B',T')
        \tkzMarkAngle[fill=blue, fill opacity=0.2,mkpos=.2, size=0.7](T',C',A')
        \tkzDrawSegments[thick](B',T') % Must be traced before STA angle
        \tkzMarkAngle[fill=blue!20,fill opacity=0.8,mkpos=.2, size=0.7](S',T',A')

        % Draw segments.
        \tkzDrawSegments[thick,dashed](A,C C,T)
        \tkzDrawSegments[thick](A,B A,T)

        \tkzDrawSegments[thick,dashed](A',C' C',T')
        \tkzDrawSegments[thick](A',B' A',T')

        {%style only afects commands inside {}
        \tikzset{line style/.append style={<->},>=Stealth} 
            \tkzDrawLine[add=1cm and 4cm](S,T)
            \tkzDrawLine[add=1cm and 3cm,dashed,color=black!30](S,U)
            \tkzDrawLine[add=1cm and 4cm](S',T')
        }

        % Draw points.
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white,size=4pt](A,B,C,U)
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=5pt](O,T,S)

        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white,size=4pt](A',B',C')
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=5pt](O',T',S')

        %Point labels
            \tkzLabelPoints[color=blue,opacity=.7,above left](B,B',U) 
            \tkzLabelPoints[color=blue,opacity=.7,below left](A,A')
            \tkzLabelPoints[color=blue,opacity=.7,above right =5pt](O,S,T,O',S',T')

            % Label the angles.
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos =1.2, rotate=25](A,B,T){$180-\theta$}
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos =-.4](T,C,A){$\theta$}
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos =-0.4](A,T,S){\contour{blue!20}{$\theta$}}

            %Using pure tikz code           
            \draw[line width=5pt,draw=white, postaction={draw=black, thick,Stealth-}] (B)
                ++(290:45pt) to [in=0,out=290]
                ++(-1.2,-1.5) node[anchor=east] {\contour{white}{\Large $180-\theta$}};
            \draw[line width=5pt,draw=white, postaction={draw=black, thick,Stealth-}] (B') % Option using controls
                ++(290:25.pt) .. controls (8.6,1.1) and (6.4,0.1) .. ++(-2,1) node[anchor=south] {\contour{white}{\Large $180-\theta$}};
            %%%%%%
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos =-1](T',C',A'){\Large $\theta$}
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos =-1](A',T',S'){\contour{white}{\Large $\theta$}}

            % Label the lines
            \tkzLabelLine[pos=2.5,blue,right](S,T){\Large$\ell$}
            \tkzLabelLine[pos=2.15,blue,right](S',T'){\Large$\ell$}

            %Some tikz node text...
            \draw node [anchor=west] at (-4,6) {\verb+\tkzDefShiftPoint[O](2.5,3.2){S}+};
            \draw node [anchor=west] at (-4,5.5) {\verb+\tkzTangent[from=S](O,A) \tkzGetPoints{U}{T}+};

            \draw node [anchor=west] at (4.5,6) {\verb+\tkzTangent[at=T'](O')\tkzGetPoint{h'}+};
            \draw node [anchor=west] at (4.5,5.5) {\verb+\tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=3.5](T',h')\tkzGetPoint{S'}+};


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

%AT is a chord of a circle, and B is a point on the circle distinct from A and T. \ell is a
%tangent line to the circle at T. \angle{ABT} and one of the angles between AT and \ell are
%supplementary angles.

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (0,0) circle (1.5);

\path (230:1.5) coordinate (A) (110:1.5) coordinate (B) (325:1.5) coordinate (B') (20:1.5) coordinate (T);
\draw[fill] (T) circle (1.5pt);
\path let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+\n2)}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A) +({0.5*(\n1+\n2)+180}:0.15)$){\textit{A}};
\path let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*((\n1-180)+\n2)}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(B) +({0.5*((\n1-180)+\n2)+180}:0.15)$){\textit{B}};
\node[anchor=200, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(T) +(20:0.15)$){\textit{T}};


%Line \ell is drawn. T is to be the midpoint of the drawn line.
\path[name path=line_ell] ($(T) +(110:1.25)$) -- ($(T) +(-70:1)$);
\path[name path=right_arrowhead_of_line_ell] (1.5,0) -- (1.75,0);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=line_ell and right_arrowhead_of_line_ell, by=a_point_near_right_arrowhead_of_line_ell}];
\coordinate (right_arrowhead_of_line_ell) at ($(a_point_near_right_arrowhead_of_line_ell) +(-70:1.4)$);
\path let \p1=($(T)-($(right_arrowhead_of_line_ell)$)$) in coordinate (left_arrowhead_of_line_ell) at ($(T) +(110:{veclen(\x1,\y1)})$);
\draw[latex-latex] (left_arrowhead_of_line_ell) -- (right_arrowhead_of_line_ell);
\node[anchor=110, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(right_arrowhead_of_line_ell) +(-70:0.1)$){$\ell$};


%Point S is located.
\coordinate (S) at ($(T) +(110:1.55)$);
\draw[fill] (S) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=200, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(S) +(20:0.15)$){\textit{S}};


%Chords of the circle are drawn.
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw[dashed] (B') -- (A);
\draw[dashed] (B') -- (T);
\draw (A) -- (T);
\draw (A) -- (T);
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (B) -- ($(T) +({\n1+180}:0.55)$);



%The marks indicating the measures \angle{ATS} and \angle{AB'T} are drawn. They are labeled \theta.
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(A)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in ($(T) +(110:0.25)$) arc (110:{\n1+180}:0.25);
\draw let\p1=($(A)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={0.5*((\n1+180)+110)-180}, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(T) +({0.5*((\n1+180)+110)}:0.3)$){$\theta$};
%
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(B')-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(B')$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(B') +(\n1:0.25)$) arc (\n1:{\n2+180}:0.25);
\draw let \p1=($(B')-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(A)-(B')$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[anchor={0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))-180}, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(B') +({0.5*(\n1+(\n2+180))}:0.3)$){$\theta$};


%The marks indicating the measures \angle{ATS} and \angle{AB'T} are drawn. They are labeled \theta.
\draw[draw=blue] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(B) +(\n2:0.35)$) arc (\n2:{\n1-180}:0.35);


%\draw[latex-,shorten <=1pt] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(B)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)}, \n3={0.5*((\n1-180)+\n2)} in ($(B) +(\n3:0.45)$) to[out=\n3, in=0, looseness=2] ++(-20pt,7.5pt) node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\tiny]{$180^\circ-\theta$};

\node[inner sep=0pt] at (-1.8,1.26) (a) {\tiny $180^\circ-\theta$};
    \draw[>=latex,->] (a.south) to[bend right=60] +(.9,-.15);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: +1 but I guess the OP wants the arrow point towards the angle. Perhaps try `\draw[latex-,shorten <=1pt] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)},
\p2=($(B)-(T)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)}, \n3={0.5*((\n1-180)+\n2)} in ($(B)
+(\n3:0.45)$) to[out=\n3, in=0, looseness=1] 
++(0,-12.5pt) to[out=180, in=-60, looseness=1] 
++(-20pt,20pt) node[anchor=south east,
inner sep=0, font=\tiny]{$180^\circ-\theta$};`

Comment: @marmot: Oh, didn't know; of course! Thank you! ;)

Comment: I'm still not sure (because my crystal ball ran out of power ;-), but perhaps the OP wants the arrow to point to the angle from the other, i.e. inner, side

Comment: @marmot  Nice hack!  I only replaced ` ++(-20pt,20pt)` with ` ++(-30pt,20pt)` and replaced the font to `\scriptsize`.

Comment: @marmot  What was wrong with my code?

Comment: @user74973 There is nothing wrong but I thought you yourself found it unappealing. When looking at the result, I was thinking you were referring to the shape of the curve. I am sorry if I got it wrong.

Comment: @marmot The code I had rendered the arrow bowed the wrong way.  Yes, your code gave me what I wanted. I guess that concatenating two `(P) to[out=*, in=**] (Q)  to[out=*, in=**]` together made it bowed "the right way."

Comment: @user74973 Yes. If you want to have a smooth curve, make sure that the `out` and the successive `in` differ by 180.